# Definition of nonsingular measurable transformation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading a book's chapter, and am confused about the following definition:

> Def: A measurable transformation $S:X\rightarrow X$ on a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is nonsingular if $\mu(S^{-1}(A))=0$ for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(A) = 0$.

I am not quite sure what does this definition says. Does it just say that $\mu(S^{-1}(A))=0$ implies $\mu(A) = 0$?

Comment: No, it says that $\mu(A)=0$ implies $\mu(S^{-1}(A))=0$.

Comment: Your title is deceptive. This definition is defining the term "nonsingular measurable transformation", not the term "nonsingular measure space".

Comment: @LeeMosher I fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @sleevechen Do you remember which book you were reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says the preimage of a null set is null.